# How to edit div class with capybara

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I have a (I hope) simple question. Is there a way to change something like

`<div id='THE_ID' class='filter_group'> subtags </div>`
to

`<div id='THE_ID' class='filter_group open'> subtags </div>` in capybara?

This website I'm looking at has a non-descript `<a>` tag as a button that edits the div class as seen above. 
I'd rather click the `<a>` tag but it being non-descript has no information. No name, no id, no href, nothing.

I'm new to rails and capybara so please forgive me if I'm missing something simple

The code block I am looking at is

```
   <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_divDateRange" class="filter_group">
        <label class="header">Date Range 
           <span class="label two-line"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_lblDateFrom">4/14/2018</span><br><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_lblDateTo">6/14/2018</span></span>
           <a></a>
        </label>
     <div class="list">
         RADIOBUTTONS and FIELDS
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is possible using JS, however then you're not really testing the site (assuming you're testing and not just scraping).  To do it via JS with Capybara 3.2+ you could do

```
page.find("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_divDateRange").execute_script("this.classList.add('open');")
```

Prior to 3.2 you would need to do something like

```
el = page.find("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_divDateRange")
page.execute_script("arguments[0].classList.add('open');", el)
```

That being said, there are plenty of ways to click the <a> even if it doesn't have any usable attributes (assuming it has size on the page) by scoping to it

```
page.find("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_divDateRange > .header > a").click
```

Comment: You sir are my hero. Your third solution works perfectly. I have no experience with JS so I'm glad I could avoid it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code (Sorry it's pure javascript I didn't see the part of your question where it says it's ment to be with cappybra):

```js
function yourFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_divDateRange");
   element.classList.add("open");
}
```

```css
.open {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="yourFunction()">Add class</button>


<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_divDateRange" class="filter_group">
        <label class="header">Date Range 
           <span class="label two-line"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_lblDateFrom">4/14/2018</span><br><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_as1_lblDateTo">6/14/2018</span></span>
           <a></a>
        </label>
     <div class="list">
         RADIOBUTTONS and FIELDS
     </div>
   </div>
```

The CSS part is to demonstrate that the class has beeen added.
Hope I helped you and others :)